# Expressiveness of finite memory programs

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Assume we have a simple programming language with `while`, `if`, `:=` (assignment), `input v` and `output v`. Where `input v` reads an arbitrary value into variable `v` and `output v` outputs the value in `v`. For simplicity we use boolean values only.
Further the program can only use $k$ variables but is of any finite length, and the program should not terminate.

The input-output behavior of any program can be captured in an infinite tree, where the edges are labeled by input values and the nodes with output values.

---

If we consider all possible programs, is the set of all input-output trees $\omega$-regular?

My thoughts: The programs are deterministic, only the input is not. Thus complex languages like ${(0^n1^n)^\omega}$, are not possible unless the inputs help us. On the other hand the length of a program is unspecified, which makes complex computations possible if the program is only long enough.

Do you have pointers where I should research? Any hints and comments are welcome, thanks.

EDIT: I guess the language is not regular. Though its not a prove the following is a convincing argument I think. Actually ${(0^n1^n)^\omega}$ is a possible output for a program. The program has $n$ `output 0` statements, followed by $n$ `output 1` and all that in a `while` loop. However $0^110^210^310^4\dots$ is not possible, for any program of finite length with finite memory. For some $\omega$-automaton to differentiate these two cases and all similar cases is too much, I think